# How do I extend the time a session expires if I have refreshed the page in cgi-perl?

Tags: perl, session, cookies

I am using CGI::Session module. I have created a session and using a session ID have created a cookie and sent to the browser whenever the user clicks on the login button and the credentials are valid.

```
use CGI::Session;
use CGI::Session::Tutorial;
use CGI::Session::Driver::file;

my $session = new CGI::Session("driver:File", undef, 
                               {Directory => "/tmp/sessions"});         
my $sid = $session->id();   

my $cookie = $query->cookie(-name   => "CGISESSID",
                            -value  => $session->id,
                            -domain => 'xyz.com',
                             path   => "/");

print "Set-Cookie: $cookie\n";  

$session->param("UserName", $loginUserName);
$query->hidden( 'UserName', $loginUserName);

$session->expire("UserName", '1m');
$session->expire('+15m'); 
$session->flush();
```

When I go to the next page, e.g. "Welcome" I check if the session exists with the cookie ID. If yes, it loads the session else it creates a new session.If it loads the session, I want the expire time to increment by +15 minutes. Is this taken care of by the session module? Also, if there is any activity in the welcome page, I want the session expire time to keep increasing, if inactive the session should expire after 15 minutes of idle time.

```
my $cookieSid = $query->cookie("CGISESSID") || undef;
my $session;

if ($cookieSid) {
    $session = new CGI::Session(undef, $cookieSid,
                                {Directory=>'/tmp'});
} else {
    create a new session/redirect to login page
}
```

I do not see the timestamp of the session created in tmp/sessions folder changing,which means that the expiration time hasn't been updated to 15 min from the last active instance.

Also, is it a good practice to have the cookie expire at the time when the browser is closed?

Comment: I've just spent two minutes cleaning up the formatting of your code. Please consider doing it yourself in the future. If you want a group of strangers to read and understand your code, it is surely only polite to make that task as easy as possible,

Comment: Also, please stop using indirect object notation (`new CGI::Session(...)`) to create your objects. The less error prone version is `CGI::Session->new(...)`.

Comment: As I have mentioned before, you need to understand the request/response cycle of HTTP.  Whatever program is on the server does not know what is happening on the client *unless* there is a request from the client. "*If there is any activity in the welcome page, I want the session expire time to keep increasing*" ... In that case, you need to make sure the client associates that activity with requests to your server.

Comment: Yes, I do understand the cycle. How to ensure that the client associates that activity with requests to my server. Can you help me with an example?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the session to expire in 15 minutes from the time when the CGI script is accessed, you set it like this

```
$session->expire('+15m');
```

It's covered in the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/CGI-Session-4.48/lib/CGI/Session.pm#expire())

Comment: I have edited my code. I have already done that. Does this take care of the session time being extended to 15 minutes from the time it was last active. I do not see the update in the sessions created in /tmp/sessions

Comment: Looks like you only set it when you create the session rather than each time it's accessed